# How to return the result in xdmp:spawn-function() in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I am using `xdmp:spawn-function()` in my code but it is not returning the value. is there any way to return the value from `xdmp:spawn-function()`

Comment: You might also consider `xdmp:invoke-function()`

Answer (score 1):

Apply the `result` option and set to `true()`:

> **result**
> Return a value future for the result of the spawned task. This value future can bound be to a variable without waiting so that work can proceed concurrently with the spawned task. When the calling request uses the value future in any operation, it will automatically wait for the spawned task to complete and it will use the result. For an example, see [The second example](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:spawn#spawnresultex).

```
(:
   This example uses the <result> option to use the results of a
   spawned task in the query
:)  
let $x := xdmp:spawn("/oneplusone.xqy", (),
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <result>{fn:true()}</result>
  </options>
)
return
($x + 2)
```

Comment: Here I can see the first parameter is module but in my case I need to pass a function as first parameter. Could you please suggest a solution @Mads Hansen

Comment: The same `<result>` option can be applied to `xdmp:spawn-function()` as well as `xdmp:spawn()`. I was just pasting from the documentation showing how that option is applied to either of them. The point being to apply the options to the third parameter and indicate that you want to return the results.